# Icon burger bar only displaying one line

Tags: css, menu, elementor

I'm using an Elementor template that's only displaying a line for the hamburger menu instead of three.

I've tried one or two things (e.g. pseudo box shadow) but it's not working.

Can someone help me? I'm really desperate, I have a deadline and don't know if I'll manage it.

Thanks so much in advance!!!

The html and CSS are:

```css
.mean-container .mean-bar {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #0c1923;
    padding: 4px 0;
    min-height: 42px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 13px 13px 11px 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal span {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mean-bar">
    <a href="#nav" class="meanmenu-reveal" style="right: 0px; left: auto; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; font-size: 18px;"><span><span><span></span></span></span></a>
    <nav class="mean-nav">
```

Comment: I managed to fix this, but the solution is too complicated to post here -- sorry. Basically there is some jquery code that inserts "</span></span></span>" (after closing and re-opening) well I erased that and replaced it with a trigram hamburger symbol (not ideal, but it works.) Also removed the font size from the jquery code. Then I removed that negative text indent, fixed the font sizes, colors, etc. So the solution involved editing the style and jquery mostly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is you have created nested span, So because of that output shows only one line.

```css
body{
background:#000;
}
.mean-container .mean-bar {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #0c1923;
    padding: 4px 0;
    min-height: 42px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 13px 13px 11px 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.meanmenu-reveal span {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    width:15px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mean-bar">
    <a href="#nav" class="meanmenu-reveal" style="right: 0px; left: auto; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; font-size: 18px;"><span></span><span></span><span></span></a>
    <nav class="mean-nav">
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for answering Mr. Lazy. Will try it amount.

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't worked.

Comment: Mr. Lazy. It has finally helped me. As you pinpointed the problem I was able to "attack" it better. Still haven't solved it but I'll keep trying.

Comment: @PatPadilla It is running ok in my snippet. But as you're saying, it is not working in your code. So please paste **Jsfiddle** link of your code in comment.

Comment: mr.ugly, seriously?